# Searching data from gridview excluding its casing

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this code that searches a list and returns the title if it matches the search word, but currently if I try searching for 'Prasad', it does not return the result. As in the list, is it 'prasad'.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearchStudent.Text.Trim()))
        {

            lstUnAssStudentDTO = lstUnAssStudentDTO.Where(u => u.FirstName.Contains(txtSearchStudent.Text.Trim())).ToList();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting them to either lower or upper like this & compare:-

```
 lstUnAssStudentDTO = lstUnAssStudentDTO
              .Where(u => u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(
                          txtSearchStudent.Text.ToLower().Trim())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearchStudent.Text.Trim()))
        {

            lstUnAssStudentDTO = lstUnAssStudentDTO.Where(u => u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(txtSearchStudent.Text.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();

        }
```